# c++ vector cant output

Tags: c++, vector

Hi im new to c++ and currently trying to use vectors so I wrote a code to find all prime numbers until the given limit I tried to output it with cout and it worked so problem is vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using  namespace std;

int main(){
    int limit,x,i,j;

    vector<int> PrimeNumbers;

    cin >> limit;   
    for(i = 1;i<limit;i++){
        for(j = 1;j<=i;j++){
            if(i%j == 0){
                x++;    
            }
        }
        if(x == 2){
            PrimeNumbers.push_back(i);  
        }
        j = 0;
        x = 0;
    }   
    for(int a = 0;a<PrimeNumbers.size();a++){
        cout <<PrimeNumbers[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

So when ı run it ı just get bunch of zeros.Can you please help?

Comment: How about: `cout <<PrimeNumbers[a] << endl;` ??

Comment: Change `cout << PrimeNumbers[a]`

Comment: and declare `i` and `j` inside the `for` loop would make you and the compiler find the errors more easily

Comment: One way to avoid this particular problem is to use a [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to display all numbers without counting them - `for (auto Number : PrimeNumbers) cout << Number << endl;`

Comment: Now you have learned why you should declare your loop variables inside your for loop.  The smaller the scope they exist, the less chance you accidentally use the wrong variable.  Declaring all local variables at the top of your function is a c++ anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with the code

The first being that you never initalize `x`, so to fix that just say `x = 0`

Another problem being that you are printing out index `[i]` at the end instead of `[a]`

Changing those should fix your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't going to use `i` and `j` outside of the loop, you should declare them inside the `for`loop

```
int limit;
int x = 0;
....
for(int i = 1;i<limit;i++){
    for(int j = 1;j<=i;j++){
     ...
    }
}
```

Then it should be clear that doing this is wrong (and will generate compiler errors in this case since `i` is not defined outside of the `for` loop)

```
for(int a = 0;a<PrimeNumbers.size();a++){
   cout <<PrimeNumbers[i] << endl; // should be a now, i no longer exists
}
```